# Why does this "Is" test fail with this comparison?

Tags: vb.net, user-controls

I have this code to compare the value of two control tag values:

```
Protected Function GetLabelTextForTag(tagVal As String) As String
    Dim CoName As String = ""
    For Each cntrl As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf cntrl Is Label Then
            If DirectCast(cntrl, Label).Tag Is tagVal Then
                CoName = DirectCast(cntrl, Label).Text
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Return CoName
End Function
```

Even when I get to this line, though:

```
If DirectCast(cntrl, Label).Tag Is tagVal Then
```

...and Tag is the same as tagVal ("1"), the next line is not reached - "1" is not seen as being the same thing as "1"

Not being familiar with VB, I thought maybe the "Is" was the problem. But the reason I used "IS" to begin with, though, is because when I first tried this:

```
If DirectCast(cntrl, Label).Tag = tagVal Then
```

...I got, "*Error   1   Option Strict On disallows operands of type Object for operator '='. Use the 'Is' operator to test for object identity.*"

The function is called by an event handler for a button click:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click( sender As Object,  e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim connStr As String = "SERVER=PLATYPUS42;DATABASE=duckbilldata;UID=durante;PWD=pondscum"
        Dim upd8DML As String = "UPDATE CustomerCategoryLog SET Category = 'Exploding' WHERE Unit = @Unit And MemberNo = @MemberNo AND Custno = @CustNo"

        Dim coName As String
        Dim argVals(2) As String
        Dim _Unit As String
        Dim _MemberNo As String
        Dim _CustNo As String
        Dim curTagVal As String

        For Each cntrl As Control In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf cntrl Is CheckBox Then
                If DirectCast(cntrl, CheckBox).Checked = True Then
                    curTagVal = CStr(DirectCast(cntrl, CheckBox).Tag)
                    coName = GetLabelTextForTag(curTagVal)
                    argVals = GetArgValsForCompanyName(coName)
                    _Unit = argVals(0)
                    _MemberNo = argVals(1)
                    _CustNo = argVals(2)
                    Using conn As New SqlConnection(connStr), _
                        cmd As New SqlCommand(upd8DML, conn)
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CoName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = coName
                        conn.Open
                        cmd.ExecuteScalar()
                    End Using
                End If
            End If
        Next
End Sub
```

I'm looking for labels and checkboxes with the same tag value, because I'm dynamically creating some pairs of these controls, and need to know which corresponding checkboxes are checked for which labels. I create them (a few, this is just a test) like so:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim sqlConnection1 As New SqlConnection("SERVER=PLATYPUS42;DATABASE=duckbilldata;UID=durante;PWD=pondscum")
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader

        cmd.CommandText = "select C.CompanyName from CustomerCategoryLog CCL join Customers C on C.CustNo = CCL.Custno where CCL.Category = 'New' and C.Active <> 0 order by C.CompanyName"
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1

        sqlConnection1.Open()

        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        ' Data is accessible through the DataReader object here.
        If reader.HasRows Then
            Dim i As Integer = 0

            While reader.Read()
                i = i+1
                If i > 12 'There are thousands...just grab the first dozen for this test
                    Exit While
                End If

                Dim lblCompanyName = New Label()
                lblCompanyName.Tag = i.ToString() 'ID not available...?!?
                lblCompanyName.Text = reader.Item(0).ToString()
                Me.Controls.Add(lblCompanyName)

                Dim ckbx = New CheckBox()
                ckbx.Tag = i.ToString()
                ckbx.Checked = True
                Me.Controls.Add(ckbx)
            End While
        End If
        reader.Close()

        sqlConnection1.Close()
    End Sub
```

I may as well add the only other bit of code on the form, too, for good measure:

```
Protected Function GetArgValsForCompanyName(coName As String) As String()
        Dim args(2) As String
        Dim sqlConnection1 As New SqlConnection("SERVER=PLATYPUS42;DATABASE=duckbilldata;UID=durante;PWD=pondscum")
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader

        cmd.CommandText = "select Unit, MemberNo, CustNo from Customers WHERE CompanyName = @CoName"
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CoName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = coName
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1
        sqlConnection1.Open()

        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        ' Data is accessible through the DataReader object here.
        If reader.HasRows Then
                args(0) = reader.Item(0).ToString()
                args(1) = reader.Item(1).ToString()
                args(2) = reader.Item(2).ToString()
        End If
        reader.Close()
        sqlConnection1.Close()

        Return args
    End Function
```

When is "1" not "1"?

Comment: You cast the control `DirectCast(cntrl, Label)` but leave `Tag` as an object, which is probably why the `Is` fails. Try calling `ToString` on `Tag` and using the `=` operator again. (If it still complains then use `Tag.ToString().Equals(tagVal)`

Comment: You could probably benefit by creating a UserControl with a Label and CheckBox to make this easier.  You don't need the HasRows before a While Read loop — if there aren't any rows, the while loop will just be skipped.

Comment: Also you aren't setting your other parameters in the Update Query.

Comment: [**Please do not put tags in the title**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, Tag is an Object not a String hence with option strict on you get the issue, try

```
If DirectCast(cntrl, Label).Tag.ToString() = tagVal Then
```

Using Is you are comparing references not values.

Fixed this for you too

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click( sender As Object,  e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            Dim connStr As String = "SERVER=PLATYPUS42;DATABASE=duckbilldata;UID=durante;PWD=pondscum"
            Dim upd8DML As String = "UPDATE CustomerCategoryLog SET Category = 'Exploding' WHERE Unit = @Unit And MemberNo = @MemberNo AND Custno = @CustNo"

            Dim coName As String
            Dim argVals(2) As String
            Dim _Unit As String
            Dim _MemberNo As String
            Dim _CustNo As String
            Dim curTagVal As String

            For Each cntrl As Control In Me.Controls
                If TypeOf cntrl Is CheckBox Then
                    If DirectCast(cntrl, CheckBox).Checked = True Then
                        curTagVal = CStr(DirectCast(cntrl, CheckBox).Tag)
                        coName = GetLabelTextForTag(curTagVal)
                        argVals = GetArgValsForCompanyName(coName)
                        _Unit = argVals(0)
                        _MemberNo = argVals(1)
                        _CustNo = argVals(2)
                        Using conn As New SqlConnection(connStr), _
                            cmd As New SqlCommand(upd8DML, conn)
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Unit", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = _Unit
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@MemberNo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = _MemberNo
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CoName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = coName
                            conn.Open
                            cmd.ExecuteScalar()
                        End Using
                    End If
                End If
            Next

End Sub
```

Comment: But `String` *is* a reference type.

Comment: I haven't checked what is surfaced by Tag, it's possible that it isn't a direct reference.  Probably worth a de-complile to check.

Comment: @djv try  adding a label to a form and then       Label1.Tag = new String("Test")
        Dim check as Boolean
        check = label1.Tag is "Test"

Comment: @djv - interesting one here, it's about the String being Interned or not.  When comparing strings. If objA and objB are strings, the ReferenceEquals method returns true if the string is interned. It does not perform a test for value equality. In the following example, s1 and s2 are equal because they are two instances of a single interned string. However, s3 and s4 are not equal, because although they are have identical string values, that string is not interned.

Comment: `Tag` is intended to take arbitrary user data, so it is exposed as `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why the original code didn't work, but chaning it to the following does:

```
Protected Function GetLabelTextForTag(tagVal As String) As String
    Dim CoName As String = ""
    Dim lblTag As String
    For Each cntrl As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf cntrl Is Label Then
            lblTag = CStr(DirectCast(cntrl, Label).Tag)
            If lblTag = tagVal Then
                CoName = DirectCast(cntrl, Label).Text
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Return CoName
End Function
```

Comment: See the answer below.  The original code didn't work because you used `Is` to compare, which does a check for reference equality.  `String` is a reference type, with the result that if you compare two different instances of "1" to each other using `Is` they may not compare equal---you may have two different String objects in different locations that each contain the value "1".  When you compare `String` to `String` using `Operator =`, it performs a value comparison.

Comment: You could also use `For Each cntrl As Label In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Label)` and get rid of the `If TypeOf` code. Your `cntrl` will then actually only be a `Label` so you won't need the `DirectCast`. Instead `cntrl.Tag` would work as would `cntrl.Text`.